# How to add a new line in multiple existing csv files using R?

Tags: r, csv

I want to read multiple csv files into R, but the csv files don't en with a new line.
When I try to read csv files i get this error message "Files must end with a newline" so in order to fix that for one single csv file this code which works fine:

```
# Add blank row
blank <- ""

# csv file name
csv_name <- "testfile.csv"

# writing row in the csv file
write.table(blank, file = csv_name, sep = ";",
            append = TRUE, quote = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

But I don’t know how to scale this when I have multiple csv files (in the same folder) and all the files have the same problem: they don’t end with a new line. I have tried but failed to find a good way to write a loop or to use purrr map functions. A suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you need to just add a newline to each file, R is a bit overkill. Perhaps just `echo >> somefile.csv` on the bash shell prompt should work.

Comment: thanks @r2evans you are most likely right about that, but I have never used bash shell so R is what I'm used to

Comment: `write("\\n", "somefile.csv", append=TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `R` for this task, you could use

```r
my_path <- "."

my_csv_list <- list.files(path = my_path, pattern = ".csv$")

blank <- ""

for (file in my_csv_list) {
  write.table(blank, file = file, sep = ";",
              append = TRUE, quote = FALSE,
              col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

or instead of a `for`-loop

```r
sapply(my_csv_list, 
       function(file) 
         write.table(blank, file = file, sep = ";",
                     append = TRUE, quote = FALSE,
                     col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE))
```

Just set `my_path` to the path containing your `.csv`-files. `file.path` could be useful for this.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, but many thanks @martingal your solution helped me a lot! I'm very grateful!